# How to add values from selectedData input to a list?

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash

I build a Plotly Dash web app to display sensor data. I want to have a map where I can select the stations and therefore I can see the time series chart.

This is my callback right now:

```
@app.callback(
    Output('time_series1', 'figure'),
    Input('map_sensors', 'selectedData'))

def display_selected_data(selectedData):
    if selectedData is None: # Plot whole Dataframe if nothing is selected.
        fig = px.line(data_frame=df, x='date.utc', y='value', color='location')
    
        return fig
    
    else:
        selectedData['points'][0]['customdata'][0] # This line shows me the name of the location and I want to add this to a list
        return
```

I can show the location in the selected data. Now my question is, how can I add this to a list?

My goal ist to filter the dataframe like this `dff2 = df[df.location.isin(selected_locations)]` so that I only plot the selected locations.

My full app right now:

```
from jupyter_dash import JupyterDash
import plotly.graph_objs as go
from dash import Dash, dcc, html, Input, Output, State
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px
import json

loc = pd.read_csv('location_sensors.csv')
df = pd.read_csv('measurement.csv')
style = {'width': '50%', 'height': '500px', 'float': 'left'}

# Build small example app.
app = dash.Dash(__name__)

styles = {
    'pre': {
        'border': 'thin lightgrey solid',
        'overflowX': 'scroll'
    }
}

fig_map = px.scatter_mapbox(loc, lat="lat", lon="lon", hover_name="location", 
                           hover_data={'location':True, 'lat':False, 'lon':False}, zoom=3, height=600,
                           color='location', mapbox_style="open-street-map")
fig_map.update_layout(clickmode='event+select')

app.layout =   html.Div([
        dcc.Graph(id='map_sensors', figure=fig_map , className='six columns'),
      
    html.Div([dcc.Graph(
                    id='time_series1',
                    style={'height': 400}
                ),
])
])

@app.callback(
    Output('time_series1', 'figure'),
    Input('map_sensors', 'selectedData'))

def display_selected_data(selectedData):
    if selectedData is None:
        fig = px.line(data_frame=df, x='date.utc', y='value', color='location')
    
        return fig
    
    else:
        # Here I want to filter the dataframe to the selected locations.
        return 
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server()
```

Locations csv data:

```
lat,lon,location
51.20966,4.43182,BETR801
48.83722,2.3939,FR04014
51.49467,-0.13193,London Westminster
```

Time series data:
https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/master/doc/data/air_quality_long.csv

Comment: I think one problem is that after you click a location on the map, it will be greyed out, and when you click that same greyed out location again, the input `selectedData` will be `None` which means the app won't know you reclicked that point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your `@app.callback` decorator, I think you want your input to be `clickData` instead of `selectionData`. If you look at the first example in the documentation [here](https://dash.plotly.com/interactive-graphing), once you click a location on the map and it is greyed out, when you click it again at a later time, clickData will input a dictionary with marker information, while selectionData will input `null` (this means that dash will have trouble knowing when you click on a point again after it's been greyed out if you use selectionData instead of clickData)

You can then have a dynamic list that changes depending on locations the user selects and deselects. Also a very minor point, but I changed your DataFrame variable name from `loc` to `locs` since `.loc` is a pandas DataFrame method.

```
from jupyter_dash import JupyterDash
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import dash
from dash import Dash, dcc, html, Input, Output, State
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px
import json

locs = pd.read_csv('location_sensors.csv')
df = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pandas-dev/pandas/master/doc/data/air_quality_long.csv')

style = {'width': '50%', 'height': '500px', 'float': 'left'}

# Build small example app.
app = dash.Dash(__name__)

styles = {
    'pre': {
        'border': 'thin lightgrey solid',
        'overflowX': 'scroll'
    }
}

fig_map = px.scatter_mapbox(locs, lat="lat", lon="lon", hover_name="location", 
                           hover_data={'location':True, 'lat':False, 'lon':False}, zoom=3, height=600,
                           color='location', mapbox_style="open-street-map")

fig_map.update_layout(clickmode='event+select')

app.layout = html.Div([
    dcc.Graph(id='map_sensors', figure=fig_map , className='six columns'),
    html.Div([dcc.Graph(
        id='time_series1',
        style={'height': 400}
        ),
    ])
])

## define a list that will hold the columns of the dataframe
## this will be used to modify the px.line chart
selected_locations = list(locs['location'])

@app.callback(
    Output('time_series1', 'figure'),
    Input('map_sensors', 'clickData'))
def display_selected_data(clickData):
    ## when the app initializes
    if clickData is None:
        fig = px.line(data_frame=df, x='date.utc', y='value', color='location')

    ## when the user clicks on one of the loc points
    else:
        selection = clickData['points'][0]['customdata'][0]
        if selection in selected_locations:
            selected_locations.remove(selection)
        else:
            selected_locations.append(selection)
        fig = px.line(data_frame=df[df.location.isin(selected_locations)], x='date.utc', y='value', color='location')
    return fig
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, I really appreciate your effort. The reason why I choose `selectdedData` is, that this makes it possible to select multiple locations with shift and cntl pressed. Your solution is really clever, but after trying I get an empty graph when I click the third location for example. Is there a way to dynamically fill and empty a selection list with the values of the `selectedData` or do you recommend it not to use because of the `null`?

Comment: I can look into it more when I have some time, but I would say that you're probably going to need to make a choice between `selectedData` and `clickData`. If you use `selectedData`, you'll be able to to shift and cntrl to select multiple locations, but you won't be able to reselect anything because of the `null` issue. If you use `clickData`, you can select and deselect each location, and this will lead to an empty graph when you deselect everything unless you have a condition like deselecting everything means the app actually displays everything

Comment: Thank you for your effort I really appreciate it. I solved it. I used some parts of your solution and some parts of this from the community plotly. https://community.plotly.com/t/keeping-map-selections-and-menu-selections-in-sync-in-a-callback/57714

Comment: You're welcome @Gobrel! I am glad you were able to solve the problem